# Converting string of typescript to code but keep getting _os.platform is undefined

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo

I am trying to compile string to code using `typescript` in `react-native` but keep getting the below error in `typescript`

```
TypeError: _os.platform is not a function. (In '_os.platform()', '_os.platform' is undefined)
```

Here is the test code I made

```js
import * as ts from "typescript";
const sourceFile = ts.createSourceFile(
  "file.ts", // filePath
  "function myFunction() {}", // fileText
  ts.ScriptTarget.Latest, // scriptTarget
  true // setParentNodes -- sets the `parent` property
);
```

Any Idea how to fix this? or any alternative to using typescript compile.

I have tested reinstalling the typescript with no luck.